# Cassandra time not saved in UTC

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I need to split my timestamp to date and time separately and insert then to db columns with 'date' and 'time' cqltypes.

I was trying to insert a time value as string to Cassandra table. The time was converted to UTC (05:27:00). But while I checked table using Datastax devcenter, column was populated with value '09:37:54.935541808'. I tried to retrieve the value in spring using repository, then it was returning value as '3473746674935541808'.

How to get the correct value from table for time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the limitation of Spring-data. In Cassandra `time` value  is encoded as a 64-bit signed integer representing the number of nanoseconds since midnight.  But I don't see the `time` type listed as supported in [spring-data-cassandra documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-conversion), so you may need to write your custom converter for it, as [described in documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.mapping.explicit-converters).